# convert dataframe of lists to format where each list can be manipulated for further analysis

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe imported from csv where each 'cell' is a list of values, so the csv looks like:

> time,x,y,z
>   2020-05-01 11:38:20.177314,"['a', 'a', 'a']","['1', '2', '3']","[8.16, 0.27, 8.16]"
>   2020-05-01 11:38:20.637325,"['a', 'a', 'a']","['4', '5', '6']","[18.16, 10.27, 18.16]"

Each row in df are the x,y,z values to create a seaborn heatmap.  I need to do a number of manipulations to the data like getting a sum of all 'z' values in each row, and recreate the heatmap for each row.  I am having trouble even getting pandas to recognize the data as lists.  Rather they seem to be string objects.  I have tried `df['zList']=df['z'].tolist()`, but am still not able to work with the data as a list.

Something like:

```
sumList=[]
for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    sumList0=0
    zList0=row.zList
    print(zList0)
    for i in zList0:
        sumList0+=float(i)
    print(sumList0)
    sumList.append(sumList0)
    print(sumList)
```

will fail with error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['

but if i create the df manually

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'x':['a','b','c'], 'y':['1','2','3'], 'zList':[12,34.2,15.1]},
{'x':['a','b','c'], 'y':['4','5','6'], 'zList':[15.0,6.5,11.7]}])
```

the above code will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that comes to mind is to use `literal_eval` to solve the string vs float problem:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['z']=df['z'].apply(literal_eval)
df['sum_z']=df['z'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
```

Comment: No worries, if it solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as Accepted.